How to properly use bluetooth dongle in Fedora 39
I am running Fedora 39 completely updated. Unfortunately, whenever I connect my Apple Magic Mouse via Bluetooth it disconnects after some time. Researching this issue led me to buy a Bluetooth Dongle. This brought me one step closer to having a fully functioning mouse, but as said not 100%.
What I found until now:
Scenario a) connecting the mouse to the built in bluetooth module does not work properly, as the mouse disconnects after some time and as soon as it is reconnected, the scrolling function is broken. After repairing it, or restarting bluetooth via terminal, the mouse fully functions again for some short period until it disconnects again.
Important information: in the settings I see that my machine is visible via NAME and the paired devices (4 in total) are shown.
Scenario b) connecting the mouse to the bluetooth dongle just works randomly. If it is connected to the dongle, then everything works flawlessly. That means, it stays connected and the scrolling function works normally. However, I cannot really control to connect it to the dongle. In more detail, if the dongle is used, then I see the devices paired to the dongle in the settings (3 in total) and the machine is visible via NAME#1.
Now, I would like to know how to be able to basiacally turn off the internal bluetooth module and use the dongle instead. Unfortunately, I did not achieve this yet.
Could anyone help me out with this isse?

If anyone lands here. Check out this link to work with several dongles.
FYI: the mouse problems I mention in my question are resovled by the lates sudo dnf update command. Actually, the bluez package got updated and included a fix.
